# How to use Vite HMR (Hot Module Replacement) for Node.js on backend

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, webpack-hmr

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to use Vite's [Hot Module Replacement](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html) for a development server in Node.js (without using Express or any other framework, just plain Node.js). Just like [webpack HMR with Nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload).

The documentation of Vite isn't too helpful in case of backend HMR.

I have searched many packages like [vite-plugin-node](https://github.com/axe-me/vite-plugin-node) but these require writing special adapters and installing additional packages.

Can I use Vite's HMR with Node.js for backend code, without installing any third-party packages / plugins? How to configure Vite for that?

Additional information:

- I'm using TypeScript

Comment: You can't pull execute javascript from v8 engine. In cjs , you can remove cache but it doesn't work with esm. It cause memory leak. try this [hot-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-import)
Use built-in feature : node --watch server.js

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351312/hot-module-replacement-for-native-es-modules-browser-or-node-js